# Mysql and inserting '' (empty not null) in datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have a system that insert some datetime field as an empty string '' and **it works**.  However, i tried to install in a different machine and it fails.

It returns

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'MyDate' at row 1 0.000 sec
```

btw, i can't change the system and both system (the working one and the new one) runs on windows.

Comment: Check the **[Server SQL modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html)** in the 2 servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable [STRICT_MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) (which is enabled by default on Windows installations)

Comment: Thanks, i edited the my.ini file and commented the sql-mode line.